# NodeJS execute 'su' command and prompt for password

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

Working on a command line application. I need to allow for the user to switch to root via `su`

I've tried

```
var spawn = require( 'child_process' ).spawn,
        ls = spawn('su');

    ls.stdout.on( 'data', ( data ) => {
        console.log( "stdout: ${data}" );
    });

    ls.stderr.on( 'data', ( data ) => {
        console.log( "stderr: ${data}" );
    });

    ls.on( 'close', ( code ) => {
        console.log( "child process exited with code ${code}" );
    });
```

and also sync:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    spawnSync = require('child_process').spawnSync;

spawnSync("su");

if(fs.existsSync('./command_stdout.txt')){
  // process standard output from your command here
}
if(fs.existsSync('./command_stderr.txt')){
  // process error output from your command here
}
```

But neither of these ask me for the prompt.

Comment: Have you tried using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sudo)?

Comment: @FrancescoPezzella just playing around with that now, not sure its up to date with latest Node version as it just exits when I try and enter the password.